# how to rewrite magento2 backend menu js

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I want to rewrite **magento2 js**

The file path is `"vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/js/theme.js"`,
 what should i do?

Thanks for you helping